# Three.js see through object

Tags: three.js

How can I make an object that I can see through, I'm not talking about lowering transparency, let's say I have a cube A and my camera is inside of it, then I got another cube B that is outside of the cube A, my goal is to see cube B while I'm inside cube A while having cube A transparency at 100%. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you want to remove the faces as Cube A? Render Cube A as a wireframe? Enable some sort-of backface culling that is not oriented towards the current camera?  If none of those, then I think need to revise question to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: This should already be happening. If cube A's face directions are all outward (very likely), and the material for cube A is one sided, you won't see it. All you need to do is make cube B's material double sided.

Comment: Ok my issue is that cube A is my skybox, and it moves together with my character, and as my character moves too far I can't see cube B for example. The thing I want to do is not to remove faces, leave it as it is, I just want to see cube B just like it would be inside cube A, but actually cube B being outside of cube A.

Comment: I think I understand now. So Cube B moves outside of cube A? And therefore the skybox is to small for the environment and does not encapsulate all pieces?  What if you used a scene just for the skybox, and then your character and cube B are in a second scene above the skybox scene.